# Getting the second, third, fourth value from a table

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm trying to calculate the 1st, 2nd and 3rd, 4th-year revenues of order from a table I have.

I'm created a formula in Google Sheets to return the first non-zero value in a table:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(3:3,,SMALL(IF(J3:R3<>0,COLUMN(J3:R3),""),1))), 1, 1)
```

This does the job I need to but I'm not sure how to adapt the formula to get to the second or third values instead of the first.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be able to change the first 1 to 2, 3 etc.

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(3:3,,SMALL(IF(J3:R3<>0,COLUMN(J3:R3),""),2))), 1, 1)
```

It works for me without the array formula wrapping

```
=INDEX(3:3,,SMALL(IF(J3:R3<>0,COLUMN(J3:R3),""),2))
```

BTW if you do it like this you can pull it across to get the first, second, third etc.

```
=INDEX(3:3,,SMALL(IF($J3:$R3<>0,COLUMN($J3:$R3),""),columns($A:A)))
```

Comment: Thanks Tom! That's just what I needed.

The only issue now is that I'm getting NULL references when the column exceeds the Small index.

Any ideas how I can get around that?

Comment: In particular it's this error:

Function SMALL parameter 2 value 2 is out of range.

Comment: Ah, I figured it using an IFERROR statement.